# Why Subversion client on Linux detects my XML file as binary?

Tags: linux, file, svn, binary

I have strange error with `svn` client on Linux.

I would like to add `test.xml` file to repository. This file is standard XML text file with only Latin characters (no BOM) and with Linux end-of-line (`LF` only). But my `svn` client fails with:

```
[mn@mn testy]$ cat test.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>test</Test>
<Test>89012345678901234</Test>
[mn@mn testy]$ file test.xml
test.xml: XML document text
[mn@mn testy]$ svn add test.xml
svn: E200009: Can't set 'svn:eol-style': file '/home/mn/testy/test.xml' has binary mime type property
```

The same operation works on Windows environment. On both I have configuration with auto-props:

```
*.xml = svn:eol-style=native
```

On both I have `svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)`.

I can workaroud it:

1. add file on Windows
2. add `svn:mime-type=text/xml` into auto-props, so it looks like:

   ```
   *.xml = svn:mime-type=text/xml;svn:eol-style=native
   ```
3. `svn add` with `--no-auto-props` option and then use `svn propset`
4. add empty file, then edit it

But I would like to do it by simply adding file.

Why Subversion client on Linux detect this file as binary?

Comment: What does "file test.xml" say?

Comment: `test.xml: XML document text`

Comment: Workaround: `svn add --no-auto-props`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a real solution, but some remarks that may help:

- Normally, mime-types are set explicitly by the user of by auto-props.
- I have found a reference how files are marked as binary: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.forcvs.binary-and-trans.html Perhaps this helps to understand how it works.
- Have you checked if the file is made executable in Linux, so that Subversion thinks it is a binary file?

With Subversion 1.8 on the client, you have the so called [Repository Dictated Configuration](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops), so the following should work under all circumstances:

1. Include at the root of your repository (/ or /trunk) the property `svn:auto-props` with the value `*.xml = svn:mime-type=text/xml;svn:eol-style=native`
2. When you now add a new file (on Windows and Linux), and the file has the ending `.xml`, Subversion should add as property to the file `svn:mime-type` and `svn:eol-style`. There should be no magic involved to see if the file is binary, and to have set the mime-type to something like `text/*` should ensure that the file is not interpreted as a binary file.

Comment: Thanks. I have also found that in Fedora there is some magic, libmagic: http://www.queryhome.com/34785/svn-add-xml-file-works-fine-on-ubuntu-but-not-on-fedora